# Android Systemproperties.set doesn't work

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to add a property cam.sound in *framework/base/core/Java/Android/hardware/Camera.Java* so that I can use to turn on or turn off the camera shutter sound, but it seems that the `Systemproperties.set` function doesn't work. Below is my test steps:

- import Android.os.SystemProperties;
- call function whit SystemProperties.set("cam.sound", "on");

After that, the value of `cam.sound` didn't change.

Comment: Have you tried `System.setProperty()` also? `Android.os.SystemProperties` is not intended for use by applications.

Comment: I had the same issue with setting a property from code, and System.setProperty didn't resolve either. Even shelling out and exec-ing setprop didn't work from code. But, if I set a breakpoint, manually run adb setprop ..., the changes would be "seen" by code. I even had root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need prefix name "persist.sys."

And then AndroidManifest.xml add (android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system")

And then Android.mk add (LOCAL_CERTIFICATE :=platform)